# How to track windows events in c#

Tags: c#, windows, api, events

Could anyone please suggest that how can I track windows event via c# code. For example, if user opens MS Paint and draw something, save it and close the window then how to track it down (all steps). 
Possible actions to complete the activity. User could have followed any permutation and combination to complete this.

1. Open MS Paint :-

   - a Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> Paint
   - b Start -> Run -> MsPaint -> enter
   - c windowskey + r (to open run prompt) -> mspaint -> enter
   - d double click on mspaint shortcut.
2. Draw something (Mouse and keyboard event)
3. Open Save dialog box :-

   - a Ctrl +s
   - b Alt F + S
   - c Click file menu -> choose save
   - d Click file menu -> choose save as.
4. Save the file
5. Close MS Paint :

   - a Alt + F4
   - b Hit cross button
   - c Alt F + Exit
   - d Click File menu -> exit
   - e from task bar (right click on mspaint in task bar and choose close).

Window fires some event to accomplish every request. So please suggest how can I track it down. Does window provides any API to get this information.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a keylogger, I am sure there are open source ones available somewhere on the internet.

Comment: It is more on event tracking side rather just logging the key. See point#3 has 4 ways to open a "save dialog box". So key or combination of keys are not important, but the result (save dialog box) is important. So i have to track the window event that directs OS to open a "save dialog box" (some window event for sure). If I gets that, then it won't matter what path was followed. Isn't it?

Comment: If you explain more what you are trying to do with this information we might be able to help better, for example are you trying to programmicly replicate the steps for some kind of automation testing or are you trying to record the demonstration so just capturing images of the actions would be more important? Don't fall in to the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)! Instead of asking us how to record every message, instead ask us how to solve the problem you have that you think recording every message will fix.

Comment: Ok. As I explained, suppose I have a task in which I have to open MS paint, draw rectangle, save and close it. I have to record steps how as a admin I did that (windows event). Then as a end-user, I have to perform same activity and then I have to check whether user performed the steps in correct way or not. If not then what is the solution (Admin steps in some UI format like screenshots).

Comment: Here end-user may open paint in different way than admin, but end result is MS Paint gets open. Same for opening "save dialog box". End-user may follow different step but "Save dialog box should gets open". So to check whether user has followed same steps will be "Save dialog box opened or not".
Hope it will help to visualize you the problem.

Comment: @AmneshGoel your requirement is same like creating a macro. Recording steps of each action performed. You need to implement it within your application by recording steps and maintaining a log for the purpose.

Comment: but to implement that macro, I need to know about Windows DLL or API which will allow me to record macro for other windows application like work, excel, powerpoint and so on so forth.

Comment: _Windows DLL or API_ not in my knowledge, however for tracking global mouse and keyboard event you can take this as an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library. For Microsoft office applications like word, excel you can record macros within application.

Comment: @HassanNisar : Thanks. But application macro won't work. I have to create macro via c# code so that I can keep them for future comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture windows event by watching into windows **EventLog**.

Follow this link for more details: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4857/A-realtime-event-log-monitoring-tool

MSDN example is more appropriate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten

Comment: Thanks. My requirement is bit different. Please check above conversation.